# Using socket.io sticky sessions with node.js cluster module

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Is there a way to maintain sticky sessions with socket servers in the cluster module? I have not seen any example of this yet. I was getting `{"code":1,"message":"Session ID unknown"}` errors on my client because of no sticky sessions. I tried forcing webSockets instead of polling first, but that makes connections unreliable for me, so that is not an option.

Code:

```
const cluster = require("cluster");
const numCPUs = require("os").cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  };

  cluster.on("exit", function () {
    cluster.fork();
  });
} else {
  const origin = "http://localhost:3000";
  const io = require("socket.io")(3001, {
    cors: {origin}
  });
  const {createClient} = require("redis");
  const redisAdapter = require("@socket.io/redis-adapter");
  const pubClient = createClient({ host: "localhost", port: 6379 });
  const subClient = pubClient.duplicate();

  io.adapter(redisAdapter(pubClient, subClient));

  io.on("connection", function (socket) {
    //...
  });
};
```

Comment: I asked the same question on Github after a few days. The response solved my problems. See: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/discussions/3992

Answer (score 0):

```
const { setupMaster, setupWorker } = require("@socket.io/sticky");
const { createAdapter, setupPrimary } = require("@socket.io/cluster-adapter");

if (cluster.isMaster) {
      // HTTP Server on the primary
    const httpServer = http.createServer();

    // This is the primary setup sticky session
    setupMaster(httpServer, {
        loadBalancingMethod: "least-connection"
    });

    // set up connection between master and workers
    setupPrimary();

  for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  };

  cluster.on("exit", function () {
    cluster.fork();
  });
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).